# Duvida em como Validar CNPJ com Jqyery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Após pesquisar em alguns sites, encontrei um código de validação de CNPJ em jquery, eu gostaria de fazer esta função ser ativa quando clicar no campo email, se o campo cnpj não estiver preenchido ou o valor inválido, quero que exiba um `alert`.

Meu HTML com os `input` CNPJ e Email e também com o `script` estão [neste link](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/akPXZd).

Alguém pode me ajudar? Não tenho conhecimento em Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionei o evento ao 'onBlur', que é quando o campo perde o foco, ou seja quando clica em qualquer outro campo da tela que não o input do CNPJ.

Se você adicionar o evento no 'click/focus' do campo, sempre dará erro, visto que ao clicar/receber o foco pela primeira vez ele ainda não tem um valor válido!

Não sei o quão íntegro esse código é, poderias usar algumas ferramentas (libs) que ajudariam nisso.

De toda forma, a forma com a qual eu fiz aqui não é a melhor possível, mas uma que pode te ajudar a entender o contexto.

E deixe eu dizer mais uma coisa sobre isso: Nao tem nada de jQuery sendo usado nesse código, por isso podes remover e dependência do mesmo se necessário!

Espero ter ajudado...

https://jsfiddle.net/7fLt2v32/